# Python: How to reference an object from the any() iterable

Tags: python

I'm trying to reference an object that I'm matching for.

```
import re
list = ["abc","b","c"]
if any(re.search(r"a",i) for i in list):
    print("yes")
    print(i)
```

This works, just not the last `print` command.

Is there any way to do what I'm trying do to here?

Comment: Well you know what `i` is, it's `"a"`; just `print("a")`! In general, though, you can't do this until [assignment expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) arrive, unless you unroll the loop into plain code.

Comment: Specifically, https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#scope-of-the-target shows an example of capturing such an `any` witness.

Answer (score 1):

`any` only tells you whether anything fulfilled the condition, it doesn't let you have the value. The most pythonic way to do that is probably this:

```
try:
    i = next(i for i in list if i == 'a')
    print(i)
except StopIteration:
    print('No such thing')
```

If you don't like the exception and would rather use an `if`:

```
i = next((i for i in list if i == 'a'), None)
if i:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables from `any()` do not bleed out of it's scope - they are only known inside it.

You are just matching simple letters - you can get all items from your list that have this letter in them by using a list comprehension:

```
my_list = ["abc","b","c","abracadabra"]
with_a  = [ item for item in my_list if "a" in item] # or re.find ... but not needed here

# this prints all of them - you can change it to if ...: and print(with_a[0])
# to get only the first occurence
for item in with_a:
    print("yes")
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
yes
abc
yes
abracadabra
```

Comment: More precisely, variables don't escape from the generator expression, whose value is just an argument to `any`.

Comment: @chepner Thanks - I once saw a question about any() no longer bleeding into outer scope - unable to find it now for linkage though

Comment: If memory serves, the issue is that in Python 2, the variable lives in the local scope where the generator is used (which would be the same scope in which `any` is called). In Python 3, the generator expression induces its own new scope in which the variables live.